# iPhone RS232 data transfer over WiFi/BT

Tags: iphone, serial-port, wifi, device

I would like to write a simple app that displays weight values sent from a scale.

The scale sends data (with a defined protocol) through RS232 port: considering that I cannot connect the iPhone to the Serial port, I was thinking to use a RS232/WiFi adapter (or RS232/BT adapter).

The iPhone should act as a Master and the scale a Slave: the iPhone sends a command (a simple text string) to the scale and the scale answers with the weight value.

Is the WiFi/BT a possibile solution to exchange the serial data between the iPhone and the scale ?

If yes, how can I establish the connection with the scale and then exchange the data with it ?

I'm a newbie so I would need very basic information and possibly some links to tutorials or sample code to understand how to write this app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about using the audio jack as a receiver of data?

[iPhone @ 1200BAUD](http://www.perceptdev.com/labs/iphone-rs232-at-1200-baud-no-jailbreak-required-using-2-0-sdk/)

Comment: I'd prefer a wireless connection but I will check the link you proveided. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With Wifi it's not possible cause iOS is not supporting peer-to-peer. Not sure you can do that with BT - you will have to do regular pairing and transmit over the available profiles.

Answer (score 0):

It's not wireless but you can checkout http://www.redpark.com/c2db9.html.

The other option I would recommend is to add a ethernet serial server, then you can access the scale with the browser on your iPhone.

Comment: Here is a wireless option http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/embedded-device-servers/wiport.html